# C++ and OpenCV: clustering white pixels algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv

I have a binary image (black and white pixels), and I'd like to cluster the white pixels into groups (objects), depending on the distance to each other, and retrieve the centroid of each cluster.

This is an example image in which I have to work on:

[image]

(frame on purple)

I'd like to check if a clustering approach would provide the results I am looking for, which means that I'm trying to avoid implementing an algorithm myself before knowing it will be worth it. 
Does OpenCV have a method to do what I need?

Comment: besides k-means, ISODATA clustering will be more suitable

Answer (score 2):

I know this is quite old, but maybe this answer could be helpful.

---

You can use [partition](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/clustering.html#partition), which will split an element set into equivalency classes.

You can define an equivalence class as *all points within a given euclidean distance*. This can be either a lambda function (C++11) or a functor (see both examples in the code).

Starting from this image (I removed purple border manually):

[image]

using an euclidean distance of 20 I got:

[image]

You can see that all white pixels that are within the euclidean distance are assigned to the same cluster (same color). The circles denotes the centroids for each cluster.

Code:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

struct EuclideanDistanceFunctor
{
    int _dist2;
    EuclideanDistanceFunctor(int dist) : _dist2(dist*dist) {}

    bool operator()(const Point& lhs, const Point& rhs) const
    {
        return ((lhs.x - rhs.x)*(lhs.x - rhs.x) + (lhs.y - rhs.y)*(lhs.y - rhs.y)) < _dist2;
    }
};

int main()
{
    // Load the image (grayscale)
    Mat1b img = imread("path_to_image", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

    // Get all non black points
    vector<Point> pts;
    findNonZero(img, pts);

    // Define the distance between clusters
    int euclidean_distance = 20;

    // Apply partition 
    // All pixels within the the given distance will belong to the same cluster

    vector<int> labels;

    // With functor
    //int n_labels = partition(pts, labels, EuclideanDistanceFunctor(euclidean_distance));

    // With lambda function
    int th2 = euclidean_distance * euclidean_distance;
    int n_labels = partition(pts, labels, [th2](const Point& lhs, const Point& rhs) {
        return ((lhs.x - rhs.x)*(lhs.x - rhs.x) + (lhs.y - rhs.y)*(lhs.y - rhs.y)) < th2;
    });


    // Store all points in same cluster, and compute centroids
    vector<vector<Point>> clusters(n_labels);
    vector<Point> centroids(n_labels, Point(0,0));

    for (int i = 0; i < pts.size(); ++i)
    {
        clusters[labels[i]].push_back(pts[i]);
        centroids[labels[i]] += pts[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n_labels; ++i)
    {
        centroids[i].x /= clusters[i].size();
        centroids[i].y /= clusters[i].size();
    }

    // Draw results

    // Build a vector of random color, one for each class (label)
    vector<Vec3b> colors;
    for (int i = 0; i < n_labels; ++i)
    {
        colors.push_back(Vec3b(rand() & 255, rand() & 255, rand() & 255));
    }

    // Draw the points
    Mat3b res(img.rows, img.cols, Vec3b(0, 0, 0));
    for (int i = 0; i < pts.size(); ++i)
    {
        res(pts[i]) = colors[labels[i]];
    }

    // Draw centroids
    for (int i = 0; i < n_labels; ++i)
    {
        circle(res, centroids[i], 3, Scalar(colors[i][0], colors[i][1], colors[i][2]), CV_FILLED);
        circle(res, centroids[i], 6, Scalar(255 - colors[i][0], 255 - colors[i][1], 255 - colors[i][2]));
    }


    imshow("Clusters", res);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of clusters in the image, you could use the [K-Means algorithm](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/clustering.html), which is implemented in OpenCV.

Besides that, i do not know any other easy solution for this task. If you like to implement this clustering yourself, [this paper](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dpelleg/download/xmeans.pdf) could help you, it is about an adaption of the k-means which must not have a fixed number of clusters.

Comment: The number of clusters may vary and there is no way to know beforehand how many they are. 

Yes, I guess i'll have to implement something myself